# Why am I getting a "Card Error" with my Nikon D7200 with multiple cards in both card slots?

Tags: nikon, sdcard, error

I have a Nikon D7200.  I've been having this issue since I bought it (close to a year ago) where after taking X pictures (X being anywhere from 10 to 200), I get a "Card Error" and it refuses to take more photos.

If I take the card out and insert it into another device (say, a laptop, or another camera), and then put it back into the D7200, everything works fine.  I don’t have to reformat it or do anything other than mount/unmount.  I’ve also tried things like just turning the camera off for a while/removing the battery and trying again, this does NOT help - I need to insert the card into some other device.

The D7200 has two card slots - this happens in both of them, so it isn’t the slot.  I’ve tried it with 3 different SD cards of different brands, so it isn’t the card. I also updated the firmware, no luck.

I’ve googled and haven’t found anyone else with this same problem.  Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What happens if the camera gives you a "Card Error" and you remove the card in the camera and use a different card?

Comment: The new card works, but the old one doesn't (until I 'reset' it by putting it in another device).

Comment: Hey I've same problem did you fixed?

Comment: Can you please mention the error or any photo of that? So that we can suggest you solutions 